# console.assert with empty array doesn't work as I expect

Tags: javascript

How do you make console.assert fails with [], this doesn't work:

```
a = []
[]
console.assert(a !== [])
undefined
console.assert(a != [])
undefined
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  `[]` and `[]` are different array instances and won't ever be equal to each other.

Comment: use `a.length` as a condition, or more explicitly, `a.length!=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that when you compare arrays to each other, you are checking whether their **reference** is the same, not if they have the same contents.

Arrays are objects, and each time you create a new array you are creating a new instance of the Array object. So in your example, `a` will not be equal to `[]`, even though their contents are the same, as they are two different Objects with different references.

The solution? I assume you want to check if the array is empty, so why not checking if the size of the array is 0?

```
console.assert(a.length !== 0);
```

Comment: That's what I did but not intuitive enough ;)